# PHP Mail Tutorials

Tags: php, email

Where I can find tutorials about sending mails in php without my smtp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer:
http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html

SwiftMailer:
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction